# Using Jquery Validation Plugin with Dropzone.js - I want to disable submit unless valid()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, dropzone.js

Here is the relevant dropzone.js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var dropzone3;
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  dropzone3 = new Dropzone('#dropform3', {
    maxFiles: 6,
  });
  $('#item-submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (dropzone3.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
      return dropzone3.processQueue();
    } 
    else {
      return $('#dropform3').submit();
    }
  });
```

My form uses dropzone.js for images. I currently have the Jquery validation plug-in working correctly on the text inputs, but I want to prevent the form from being submitted if there are any errors in the inputs.

This is what the code for my submit button looks like:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Upload" id="item-submit" class="btn btn-default photoform">
```

Here is the validation script:

```
$('form#dropform3').validate({
  errorElement: "div",
  rules: { 
    'photo[title]':             {required: false, maxlength: 30},
    'photo[tag_list]':          {required: false, taglength: 20}
  }
});
```

I unsuccessfully tried to create an `if statement` to disable the button using:

```
var isValid = $('form#dropform3').valid();
var dropbtn = $('#item-submit')
if (!isValid) {
  dropbtn.prop("disabled", true);                  
}
```

and

```
var isValid = $('form#dropform3').valid();
var dropbtn = $('#item-submit')
if (!isValid) {
  dropbtn.css("pointer-event", "none");                  
}
```

However, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484491/5830835) --

> when using a type="submit", your click handler is not needed because the click is automatically captured by the plugin. Also, in that case, you would use the [submitHandler](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) option to contain any code to run when the form is valid.

I briefly tried unsuccessfully to move `$('#item-submit').click(function(e)` into `submitHandler` but received an error that `dropzone3` was undefined. I do not know how to combine the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I solved this by moving

```
if ($('form#dropform3').valid()) {
```

into the click function:

```
$('#item-submit').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
if ($('form#dropform3').valid()) {});
}
```